# Relative and absolute paths on ASP.NET/IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, path

I've read many articles about relative/absolute paths, but I still can't grok this problem.

The following code is from my ASP.NET `Master` page:

```
<li><a>Reports</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/Reports/One.aspx">One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="~/Reports/Two.aspx">Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

(Note that one link has a `~` and one doesn't.)

When running the site, the first link points to `http://server/Reports/One.aspx`, and the second link points to `http://server/company/project/Reports/~/Reports/Two.aspx`.

How do I get to the root of my ASP.NET project without it ignoring whatever virtual directories are set up on IIS?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` attribute to the anchor tag. You can't use the ~ root operator with HTML tags. Only the server controls (Html or Web) can use it.

```
<a runat="server" href="~/Reports/Two.aspx">Two</a>
```

Comment: works like a charm!, thank you!, but why that it made the trick?

Comment: @dennisbot - `runat="server"` causes IIS to preprocess the tag. The ASP symbol ~ is resolved to the root of the web app and an absolute URL is delivered to the browser.

Answer (score 12):

Use `Page.ResovleUrl` for all of your files if you don't want them to be server controls with generated Ids:

```
<a href='<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Reports/Two.aspx")%>'>Two</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

A relative path is relative to the current resource, so if you were viewing

`http://yourhost/app/default.aspx`

a relative path of `reports/one.aspx` would be `http://yourhost/app/reports/one.aspx`. Note the absence of a leading `/` in the relative path. That's what makes it relative.

An absolute path, as you can probably guess, starts with a `/`, and it uses the hostname of the current resource, so that would `http://yourhost/reports/one.aspx`.

~ is an red herring. It's a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)-only addition used by various parts of ASP.NET to base your path off the current application root. So if your application root was `http://yourhost/app`, you were viewing `http://yourhost/app/views/default.aspx`, and you asked .NET for the path `~/reports/one.aspx', you would be given`http://yourhost/app/reports/one.aspx`.

~ isn't used by HTML, IIS or URLs, so if your browser sees it, it'll just use it as is.

**Note**: Some Unix servers can use `~` to map in a user's home directory, but that's just complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

Please read *[There is something about "Paths" for ASP.NET beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspnetPaths.aspx)*. It will give a complete idea on "Paths" in an ASP.NET application.