# Dynamically referencing a javascript file

Tags: asp.net, path

Kinda related to my [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674117/relative-and-absolute-paths-on-asp-net-iis), my site runs fine locally but as soon as I deploy to IIS the javascript file/s are not being called properly.

In the `<head>` tag of my `Master` page:

```
<script src='/Assets/jquery-1.4.2.min.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='/Assets/hoverIntent.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='/Assets/superfish.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='/Assets/supersubs.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This works on visual studio dev server but not on IIS. I tried adding `~` and saying `runat="server"` but it just gives some jquery error ("Unexpected character '\'" on Line 18 of the minified jquery) when trying to run it.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use a relative path?

Comment: Have you tried browsing to the paths above in your browser? the / at the start means you're defining absolute paths, so check they're still valid. eg http://yourhost/Assets/hoverIntent.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Page.ResovleUrl` for all of your files:

```
<script src='<%# Page.ResolveUrl("~/Assets/jquery-1.4.2.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: trying this i get an error "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Comment: using # and it simply doesn't work. not calling the js files. :/

Comment: Does your <Head> tag have runat="server"?